# Forget to configure a separate partition for /home

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, swap, disk-usage

I recently installed Ubuntu, manually partitioning the hard disk.

I created a 16GB partition for `/` (root), and a swap partition, with 226GB free that I intended to use for `/home`, but I forgot to add it before installing.

Is there a way to create a new partition withe the 226GB space and make this my `/home` directory?

Comment: [English](https://translate.google.co.in/) please.

Comment: Are you asking how to create a `/home` partition from free space on the harddisk?

Answer (score 1):

You must mount the partition on a temporary directory name to copy files to it the original /home. Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>).  Run it:

Find out the name of the partition

```
sudo -i
fdisk l
```

Suppose it is /dev/sda7

You create the directory

```
sudo -i 
mkdir /media/hometemp
```

Mount partition

```
mount /dev/sda7 /media/hometemp
```

To copy:

```
cd /home
cp -ax . /media/hometemp
```

This last line is the only one used to clone, attention "." the end.

Now mount the new / previous home rename the /home partition and remove the old.

```
cd /
mv /home /home.old
mkdir /home
umount /dev/sda7
mount /dev/sda7 /home
```

Now you have to find the UUID of the partition and edit the /etc/fstab file to mount the partition at startup.

```
blkid /dev/sda7
nano /etc/fstab
```

And you add these lines at the end with that reported blkid UUID.

```
# /dev/sda7 was /home
UUID=a673dafc-1032-45c2-a1b4-a615703bdaaf /home ext4 defaults 0 2
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, save file. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, close nano.

Restarting have everything working exactly the same, but with separate partitions.

Once everything is working well, delete the /home.old and /media/hometemp

```
sudo -i
rm /home.old
rm /media/hometemp
```

---

### Spanish version

Debes montar la partición en un directorio de nombre temporario
para poder copiar a ella los archivos del  /home original.
Abre una terminal.  **(Ctrl+Alt+T)**.
Ejecuta en ella:

Averiguas el nombre de la partición

```
sudo -i
fdisk -l
```

Supongamos sea /dev/sda7

Creas el directorio

```
sudo -i 
mkdir /media/hometemp
```

Montas la partición

```
mount /dev/sda7 /media/hometemp
```

Para copiar:

```
cd /home
cp -ax . /media/hometemp
```

Esta última linea es la única que sirve para clonar, atención con "." del final.

Ahora montas el nuevo /home previo renombrar el /home viejo y desmontar la partición

```
cd /
mv /home /home.old
mkdir /home
umount /dev/sda7
mount /dev/sda7 /home
```

Ahora tienes que averiguar la UUID de la partición y editar editar el /etc/fstab, para montar la partición al inicio.

```
blkid /dev/sda7
nano /etc/fstab
```

Y añades estas lineas al final con la UUID que informó blkid.

```
#/dev/sda7 was /home 
UUID=a673dafc-1032-45c2-a1b4-a615703bdaaf /home ext4    defaults        0       2
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, guarda el archivo. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, cierra nano.

Al reiniciar tendrás todo funcionando exactamente igual, pero con particiones separadas.

Una vez que todo esta funcionando bien, borras el /home.old y el /media/hometemp

```
sudo -i
rm /home.old
rm /media/hometemp
```

Comment: Please, translate your answer to English.

Comment: Done. I needed time.